# How do you loop a thread?

Tags: android, multithreading, loops, runnable

I have a thread containing a runnable.
I need this to loop infinitely unless cancelled by the user.
I have no idea how to go about this. All help is greatly appreciated.
Cheers.

Comment: Simply running a loop is easy. But you probably want the thread to process commands/work items from the main thread, right? And sleep when idle? And quit when told?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> I need this to loop infinitely unless cancelled by the user.

Obviously you can easily add a loop inside of your `run()` method:

```
  new Thread(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
          while (true) {
             // do something in the loop
          }
      }
  }).start();
```

It's always a good idea to check for thread interruption:

```
  new Thread(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
          // loop until the thread is interrupted
          while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
             // do something in the loop
          }
      }
  }).start();
```

If you are asking about how you can cancel a thread operation from another thread (such as a UI thread) then you can do something like this:

```
private final volatile running = true;
...
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        while (running) {
           // do something in the loop
        }
    }
}).start();
...

// later, in another thread, you can shut it down by setting running to false
running = false;
```

We need to use a `volatile boolean` so that changes to the field in one thread are seen in the other thread.

Comment: Perfect response. That's everything I needed. Cheers.

Comment: It is safe to use volatile boolean variable. All reads and writes to any primitive (and reference) types are always atomic (except long and double sometimes). AtomicBoolean variable is an overkill, I think.

Comment: Not sure it is "overkill" per se @Vladimir but a `volatile` will also work, yes.